# Anylogic Custom Agent not loading?

Tags: anylogic

I'm building a DES queue model in AnyLogic. I have built several models before where I make use of defining my own agent type to store agent parameters that change how they flow through a queue network, for example.  In the past this has not caused errors.  However, after building a new and incredibly simple M/M/1 queue model (source, service and sink) and defining a new agent type "MyAgent", even if I don't save or access any agent attributes I've been getting the error:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:

class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class modeltest.MyAgentTest (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and modeltest.MyAgentTest are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

It seems that perhaps the newly defined agent is not being recognized? In all of the source, service and sink blocks etc the agent type is set to "MyAgentTest"/

Any tips for troubleshooting? I've already tried rebuilding the simple model from scratch and I'm still getting the same error. If I only use a source/sink then the model runs without error. If I introduce a delay block the model will not error if the service time is very small, but if I make it larger it will error and changing it back to the original magnitude afterwards maintains the error.

I'm using AnyLogic version 8 University 8.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to the service properties. Under the "Advanced" tab, is `Agent Type` selected as "MyAgent" or as "Agent"? Similarly, go to the source properties and check the tab `Agent` and make sure "MyAgent" is selected.

Let me knows if this solves it.
[image]

Comment: The agent type is set to MyAgent in all of the blocks and I still get the error

Comment: I tried replicating the model but did not get any error. Feel free to share the model.

Comment: Here's a link, let me know if you have issues accessing it. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tcg355b20vqerc7/AAAAEWQgQDMoVVP8r0HyYCDba?dl=0) . I added what version of anylogic I'm using in the question.  Its strange because ive used custom agents before without issues, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It seemed you missed the part of my answer where I mentioned the `Agent` tab not the `Agent Type` tab for the source. It is selected as Agent in your model. Changing it fixed it. I will add an image to my answer.

Comment: In the advanced tab "MyAgent" was selected in dropdown, but in Agent tab it was not, selecting "MyAgent" in Agent tab fixed my problem

Comment: @EmileZankoul you've just made my day. This solution of lookin in the Agent tab and not the "Agent type" tab was the key. Thanks