# Anylogic: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Agent to MyAgent

Tags: anylogic

The objective is to get the closest agent on the path to the east of wait.get(0) (So the closest to the agent in the Wait Block in position 0).

The code below, throws the following error in the commented line.
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Agent to MyAgent".
All the agents I "send" along the path are type MyAgent...or so I assume.
What am I doing wrong?

```
MyAgent leading_agent;
MyAgent trailing_agent;
double separation = 0.0;

    //check that one aircraft has passed into approach
     if(moveToApproach.in.count()>0)
        {
        //check that there is at least one airplace in que
        if (wait.size()>0)
            {
             //***** The line below throws the error ******
            leading_agent = wait.get(0).getAgentNextToMe(EAST);
             //********************************************
            trailing_agent = wait.get(0);
            trailing_agent.plane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034256/anylogic-custom-agent-not-loading/66034683?noredirect=1#comment127725895_66034683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"getAgentNextToMe(EAST)" will only work in Discrete space. Since mine is Continuos, this method will not/cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have `MyAgent` agents in your `wait` block, you can use type-casting to enforce it in the code line throwing the error:

```
leading_agent = ((MyAgent)wait.get(0).getAgentNextToMe(EAST));
```

In your flow chart blocks, you can pre-define the type of agent flowing through, actually. Doing this will make the step above superfluous.

Comment: Hi Benjamin - thanks for your reply. I thought I did define the agents flowing throw by selecting the Agent type "My Agent" in Advanced tab of the block(s). Using type-casting produced the following error: "This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Continuous' and can't have behavior for space 'Discrete 2D'" - I guess that catch is that the method can only be used for Discrete space...mine is Continuous. How would I get the closest neighboring agent along a path direction in Continuous space?

Comment: Absolutely true, it is only for discrete space. Please open a new issue for the new question, SOF does not work like a forum, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow :)

Comment: Got it Benjamin and thanks for your time the feedback re:SOF. Regards, John